# Regular Expressions kicking out HTML textarea input in PHP preg_match if condition

Tags: php, regex, textarea, preg-replace, preg-match

I am at a loss on why my PHP code, the preg_match, is not accepting input from an HTML textarea input when it has parentheses or returns:

Here is the relevant PHP:

```
/* Check for Ingredient Description */
if (preg_match ('%^\s*[A-Za-z0-9\,\.\' \-\"\(\)]{30,2048}$%', stripslashes(trim($_POST['ingredient_descrip'])))) 
{
   $idscr = escape_data($_POST['ingredient_descrip']);
} 
else 
{
   $idscr = FALSE;
   echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">
      Please enter an ingredient description!</font></p>';
}
```

The custom function escape_data is as follows:

```
$dbc = mysql_connect (DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPW)
function escape_data ($data) 
{   
if (function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string')) 
{
    global $dbc; 
    // Need the connection.
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string (trim($data), $dbc);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
} 
else 
{
    $data = mysql_escape_string (trim($data));
    $data = strip_tags($data);
}
// Return the escaped value.    
return $data;
}
```

Here is the relevant HTML that calls for the textarea input:

```
<form action="ingredient_form.php" method="post" enctype="multi-part/form-data">
<fieldset>

<p><b>Ingredient Description:</b></p> 
    <p><textarea cols="100" rows="20" name="ingredient_descrip"></textarea><?php if (isset($_POST['ingredient_descrip'])) echo $_POST['ingredient_descrip']; ?></p>


</fieldset>
<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Proposed Ingredient Profile" /></div>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
```

I have tried removing the preg_match and just accepting the textarea input, then using preg_replace function to regain formatting and test with the following code:

```
if ($_POST['ingredient_descrip']) 
{
$idscr = stripslashes(trim($_POST['ingredient_descrip']));
echo "<p>" .$idscr. "</p>";
$idscr = escape_data($idscr);
echo "<p>" .$idscr. "</p>";
$idscrp = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "<br />", $idscr);

echo "<p>" .stripslashes($idscrp). "</p>";
}
```

The preg_replace doesn't seem to be doing its job either.  I put this into the textarea for testing purposes:

```
This is a (test)
Why isn't it working?
but
```

My echo results come back as:

```
This is a (test) Why isn't it working? but

This is a (test) \r\nWhy isn\'t it working? \r\nbut

This is a (test) rnWhy isn't it working? rnbut
```

The preg_replace should be substituting the \r\n with a break and then the stripslashes should get rid of the remainin escape characters.  What am I missing?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` escapes `\n` and `\r` (see [docs](http://us2.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)), which is why you have literal text `'\r\n'` and not actual newline/carriage return characters.

Comment: Thanks I took out the escape data function lines and the result gave me the formatting I wanted - now the problem is how to sanitize the data from SQL injection.

Comment: Replace newlines _before_ escaping it? Generally you'd want to escape text as the very last thing you do before inserting it. Otherwise you risk accidentally undoing some of its escapes.

Answer (score 2):

Use [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to replace new lines with `<br />` tags, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel with `preg_replace()`.

That said, your `preg_replace()` call works for me:

```
$str = <<<STR
foo
bar
baz
STR;

var_dump($str);
$str = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "<br />", $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Output:

```
string(11) "foo
bar
baz"
string(21) "foo<br />bar<br />baz"
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good alternative.  I appreciate the reply.  Any idea why my preg_match was giving me a hard time with new lines and and parentheses even though it seems I've got them covered in my regex?

Comment: @Jay As my comment above indicates, the text you were matching against contained no newlines. The newlines were converted to the literal text `'\r\n'` by the prior escaping.

Comment: @Wiseguy Thank you for the advice on both accounts.